# How to trigger re-renders in Jest using redux state changes rather than setState within components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

So Jest has a very awesome feature to allow for dynamic re-rendering of components mid-test as a result of state changes. It's illustrated in the React tutorial on their site:

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html

Here's a distilled version of the relevant code:

```
test('Link changes the class when hovered', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Link page="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</Link>
  );

  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

  // manually trigger the callback
  tree.props.onMouseEnter();

  // AUTOMATIC RE-RENDERING MID-TEST!!!!
  tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

});
```

That's awesome, except the idiomatic way as of 2017 to write React is with as few stateful components as possible, which means using Redux. However, I can't seem to get the above to work with Redux. Here's what I have:

```
export function renderWithStore(store, Component, mapStateToProps) {
  return renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...mapStateToProps(store.getState())} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

If you're wondering what `mapStateToProps` is, it's a function provided to generate the props for the tested component (just as you would with `connect`). I intentionally have moved its *calling* to be nested within `<Provider>` because obviously if you simply passed a component instance with its props (as you usually would to `renderer.create`), it wouldn't be able to respond to state changes in the store. So that's why the *component factory* is passed with its props **separately**.

And for clarity, here's what `mapStateToProps` looks like:

```
({total}) => {
    return {total}
}
```

So how can we achieve "alive" components like we can when using `setState`? How can we make the return of `renderer.create` continue to respond to redux state changes?

Perhaps, somehow calling `forceUpdate` in response to `store.subscribe` is the solution?? I'm going to try that now. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I changed my `renderWithStore` function to subscribe and force the update as just described like so:

```
export function renderWithStore(store, Component, mapStateToProps) {
  let comp;

  store.subscribe(() => {
    comp.forceUpdate();
  });

  return renderer.create(
    <Provider ref={c => comp = c} store={store}>
      <Component {...mapStateToProps(store.getState())} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

and it's not working. But it's making progress. Force update is correctly being called and I've called `console.log()` within `Component` to check whether the re-rendering is occurring. And it is in fact occurring. However the call to `component.toJSON` seems to re-render the initial component, rather than the updated one, which is still different than how it responds to `setState`. Somehow, it appears that Jest has internally made a special exception for `setState`--going to try that instead of `forceUpdate`...

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out, and I think I came up with something very useful for react developers using both redux and jest. Here it is:

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import configureStore from '../src/configureStore'

import {loadSomethingAsync} from '../src/actions/async';


export async function createStore({shouldLoad=true}) {
  const history = createHistory()
  const store = configureStore(history)

  if(shouldLoad) {
    await store.dispatch(loadSomethingAsync())
  }

  return store
}

export function connect(store, Component) {
  return (mapStateToProps) => {
    let wrapper;

    store.subscribe(() => {
      wrapper.forceUpdate();
    });

    return renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Wrapper
          ref={wr => wrapper = wr}
          store={store}
          Component={Component}
          mapStateToProps={mapStateToProps}
        />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}


class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let {store, Component, mapStateToProps} = this.props

    let props = typeof mapStateToProps === 'function'
      ? mapStateToProps(store.getState(), store.dispatch.bind(store))
      : mapStateToProps //object or undefined

    return <Component {...props} />
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```
test('do something', async () => {
  const store = await createStore()
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let {foo} = state
    return {foo};
  }

  const render = connect(store, MyComponent) // reusable with
  const component = render(mapStateToProps)  // different props


  let tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()

  store.dispatch({type: 'SOMETHING_HAPPENED'}}) 
  // or through a handler that does the same, eg: tree.props.onClick()

  tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot() // snapshot reflects state change :)


  // now let's try re-using the enclosed component within
  // our render function but with different mapStateToProps:

  let tree2 = render({foo: 'bar'}); // you can also pass a plain object
  expect(tree2).toMatchSnapshot()
});
```

And that's it. Your components are now "alive," i.e. in sync with redux, and you don't have to continually call `renderer.create()`. `connect` is basically like the `connect()` function you're used to, but with the roles of the component and state mapper reversed, allowing you to reuse the same component with different props in different tests.